# Rails field_with_errors and Bootstrap 4 vertical form

Tags: haml, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-4

I have a simple rails 5 form for New/Edit using vertical alignment using Bootstrap4.  Everything looks fine until I get an error.  The `.field_with_errors` is breaking the alignment.

It seems like the .col-x-x selectors are being ignored once the field_with_errors is introduced.  I know bootstrap 4 is still in alpha, but hoping someone has found a work around.

Here is the form:

```
.container.wow.fadeInUp{style: "visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;"}
  %h2.state New State
  .w-75
    = errors_for(@state)
    .card
      = form_for [:admin, @state] do |f|
        .card-block
          .form-group.row
            = f.label :name, class: 'col-sm-4 col-form-label'
            .col-sm-5
              = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
          .form-group.row
            .col-sm-3
              = f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can remove the field_with_error div that breaks your css

Here's a simple trick to do away with those pesky wrappers once and for all. Just add this block to your config/environment.rb file.

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  html_tag.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to find a good answer to this, as all the old answers seem to refer to `.has-error`, and this is no longer supported in Bootstrap.

An extention of the answer given by @LifterCoder, inspired by [this blog post](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=ac6e3160-74f4-4b95-8c3c-be77d68db886#gsc.tab=0), allows the `label` tags to be ignored, but still wrap the other tags with `.field_with_error` tags.

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  if instance.kind_of?(ActionView::Helpers::Tags::Label)
    html_tag.html_safe
  else
    "<div class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe
  end 

end
```